# Expecting Null equal to 'Some Value' in Protractor

Tags: protractor, code

I enter the value with this code:

```
var FirstName = element(by.name('firstName'));
FirstName.clear().sendKeys('RM');
```

The code updates the profile of the user correctly.

Now I am trying to read that value or expecting that value in Protractor Visual Studio Code with this code:

```
expect(element(by.name('firstName')).getText()).toEqual('RM');
```

I have also tried this:

```
expect(FirstName.getAttribute('firstName')).toEqual('RM');
```

but it returns a null value

How do I read the value of the First Name field?

The app code is below.
[image: r]

Comment: Please, reformat your question so it is clear what is the problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try to formulate like this: 1- Context: What type of application you are dealing with. 2 - Goal: What do you want to accomplish. 3 - What you have tried. 4 - The problem that you experienced with your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractors `getAttribute('firstName')` gets the value of the attribute firstName, not the value of the input. Your example element does not have an attribute "firstName". It has attributes id, pattern, name, placeholder, aria-*, etc..

I think you want to use the (in your case hidden) attribute 'value' instead:

```
FirstName.getAttribute('value')
```

Comment: FirstName.getAttribute('value') In this 'value' what should i write??

Comment: @Arslankhan value is an input's attribute that contains the value of the input. So the text 'value' should be 'value'. See the INPUT Tag HTML documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value